# d3 stacked bar chart: group stacked bars monthwise

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am trying to group bars monthwise using D3 so that grouped bars align below the month names on the x axis properly.
the data i am reading is from a csv file as shown below :

Month,Projected Sales/Purchase,Purchase ,Shipped ,Supplier,
JAN-17,310504,552339,259034,A,

JAN-17,610504,252339,659034,B,

FEB-17,910504,552339,259034,A,

FEB-17,210504,252339,659034,B,

FEB-17,810504,252339,659034,C,

This is what i'm trying to achieve https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vdtL.jpg

Each stacked bar in a month represents a particular supplier. And the supplier count may vary from month to month.

The following is the code that i've tried:

```
                <script>

            var svg = d3.select("svg"),
                margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 40},
                width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
                g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            var x = d3.scaleBand()
                .rangeRound([0, width])
                .paddingInner(0.05)
                .align(0.1);

            var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .rangeRound([height, 0]);

            var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

            d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
                for (i = 1, t = 0; i < (columns.length-1); ++i) 
                t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
                d.total = t;
                return d;
            }, function(error, data) {
              if (error) throw error;

            var keys = data.columns.slice(1,4);

            x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Month; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);
            z.domain(keys);

            var stack = d3.stack()
                .keys(data.columns.slice(1,4));
            var stackedData = stack(data);

            g.append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(stackedData)
            .enter().append("g")
              .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d,i) { console.info(d[i].data.Month);return d; })
            .enter().append("g").append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i){return i * 75;})
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
            .attr("width", 50);

            g.append("g")
              .attr("class", "axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 450 + ")")
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

            g.append("g")
              .attr("class", "axis")
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
            .append("text")
              .attr("x", 2)
              .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
              .attr("dy", "0.32em")
              .attr("fill", "#000")
              .attr("font-weight", "bold")
              .attr("text-anchor", "start");

            var legend = g.append("g")
              .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
              .attr("font-size", 10)
              .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(keys.slice().reverse())
            .enter().append("g")
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

            legend.append("rect")
              .attr("x", width - 19)
              .attr("width", 19)
              .attr("height", 19)
              .attr("fill", z);

            legend.append("text")
              .attr("x", width - 24)
              .attr("y", 9.5)
              .attr("dy", "0.32em")
              .text(function(d) { return d; });
            });

            </script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkwEg.jpg is the output for the above code.

Comment: You have to set **two scales** for the x axis. Please, create a working jsfiddle/plunker/codepen/whatever, because it's hard to propose a solution without testing with your "data.csv" file.

Comment: here is the link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/toni_furious/yzx7ubof